# Understanding how to make repository queries asynchronous

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous, repository

I have the following LINQ query in my repository which behaves as expected:

```
public ICollection<Address> GetManufacterAddressesFromProductId(Guid productId)
{
    return Context.Products
        .First(product => product.Id == productId)
        .Manufacturer
        .Addresses;
}
```

How do I make this call async? This is my current solution, which seems... overly long?

```
public async Task<ICollection<Address>> GetManufacterAddressesFromProductIdAsync(Guid productId)
{  
    var product = await Context.Products.FirstAsync(x => x.Id == productId);
    var manufacturerId = product.ManufacturerId;
    return await Context.ManufacturerAddresses.Where(x => x.ManufacturerId == manufacturerId ).ToListAsync();
}
```

Leaves me feeling like this isn't really doing things properly, as it has to wait for the first call to complete anyway - sort of defeats the point?

Comment: Is this Entity Framework 6 or Core?

Comment: The point of async is to free up threads while I/O-bound work is taking place. I don't think that point is being defeated here, is it?

Comment: Use `Products.Where(x => x.Id == productId).SelectMany(p => p.Manufacturer.Addresses)`

Comment: After getting the `product`, why can't you just `return product.Manufacturer.Addresses`?

Comment: I'm using EFCore

Comment: await Context.Products.Where(x=>x.Id == productId).SelectMany(x => x.Manurfacturer.Addresses).ToListAsync(); will hopefully do the trick, thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following way:

```cs
public Task<ICollection<Address>> GetManufacterAddressesFromProductId(Guid productId)
{
    return Context.Products
        .Where(product => product.Id == productId)
        .Select(product => product.Manufacturer.Addresses)
        .FirstAsync();
}
```

Also note that Sync version is not effective. Should be:

```cs
public ICollection<Address> GetManufacterAddressesFromProductId(Guid productId)
{
    return Context.Products
        .Where(product => product.Id == productId)
        .Select(product => product.Manufacturer.Addresses)
        .First();
}
```

Comment: There are multiple addresses for a manufacturer - this solution returns one I believe

Comment: No, it returns collection of Addresses. `First` returns just ONE collection.

Comment: I do apologise, you're correct. Thanks! Is this solution better than:

await Context.Products.Where(x=>x.Id == productId).SelectMany(x => x.Manurfacturer.Addresses).ToListAsync()

Comment: Actually, with SelectMany it can be better query, because my solution uses Eager Loading.

Comment: Thankyou, I have gone with the SelectMany option